# Can I createPortal from an onClick handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-portal

Given something like this:

```
import { render, createPortal } from "react-dom"

const MyPage = () => {
  const handler = () => {
    render(<MyModalDialog />, document.body)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handler}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I can conditionally render my modal dialog directly onto the body (leaving cleanup to the dialog perhaps, but that's not important for this question). This works, but the problem is there is no Context available (i.e., `useContext`).

As of v16. there is an api for this case, `createPortal`. This keeps the context around and allows rendering onto an arbitrary DOM node. But, this has no effect inside a click handler as shown above - it is meant to be returned from the `<MyPage/>` component, and react handles the actual rendering elsewhere.

So my question is - can I conditionally render an arbitrary component to a specified DOM node as part of an event handler using `createPortal` or some other API?

Answer (score 1):

A better method to do it would be having the portaled element in a separate component and having a state in your `MyPage` component that renders the modal conditionally

Something like

```js
const MyPortaledModal = () => createPortal(<MyModalDialog />, document.body)


const MyPage = () => {
  const [shouldShowModal, setShouldShowModal] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => setShowModal(prevValue => !prevValue)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleModal}>Click me</button>
      {shouldShowModal && <MyPortaledModal/>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's a very reasonable approach, but not what I'm looking for in this case.

Comment: Which need exactly does it not satisfy?